# Using groupby to classify data for plotting

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe and I'm trying to plot the values and error bars after grouping the data

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint


def classify_data():
    race = ['race1','race1','race1','race1','race2','race2','race2', 'race2']
    qualifier = ['last','first','first','first','last','last','first','first']
    participant = ['rat','rat','cat','cat','rat','dog','dog','dog']
    avgsteps =  ['223','321', '445', '165', '216', '127', '122', '214']
    measureerror = ['0.02', '0.01', '0.01', '0.05', '0.02', '0.01', '0.01', '0.05']
    id = ['a', ' b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'race': race,
         'qualifier': qualifier,
         'participant': participant,
         'avgsteps' : avgsteps,
         'measureerror': measureerror
        }
    )
```

I want to group data like:

```
 race qualifier participant avgsteps measureerror  id

0  race1     first         rat      321         0.01   b
1  race1     first         cat      445         0.01   c
2  race1     first         cat      165         0.05   d
3  race2     first         dog      122         0.01   g
4  race2     first         dog      214         0.05   h
```

I intend to create separate plot for each race type.
For instance, a plot for `race 1` with the ids on x-axis and `avgsteps` and 
error bars for `measureerror` on y-axis. I want to color the value based on 
`participant` type.

To start with, I tried

```
   df2 = (df.groupby(['race', 'qualifier'])
           )
```

This returns an object and I am not sure how to proceed.

EDIT :

```
  df = df[df.qualifier.str.contains('first')]
```

gives

```
1  race1     first         rat      321         0.01   b
2  race1     first         cat      445         0.01   c
3  race1     first         cat      165         0.05   d
6  race2     first         dog      122         0.01   g
7  race2     first         dog      214         0.05   h
```

But, I am not sure how to use groupby directly

I'd like to ask for suggestions on how to proceed

Comment: What's your expected output for the sample data?

Comment: @QuangHoang please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find an alternative without using groupby

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go


def classify_data():
    race = ['race1','race1','race1','race1','race2','race2','race2', 'race2']
    qualifier = ['last','first','first','first','last','last','first','first']
    participant = ['rat','rat','cat','cat','rat','dog','dog','dog']
    avgsteps =  ['223','321', '445', '165', '216', '127', '122', '214']
    measureerror = ['20', '30', '121', '55', '21', '121', '100', '5']
    id = ['a', ' b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'race': race,
         'qualifier': qualifier,
         'participant': participant,
         'avgsteps' : avgsteps,
         'measureerror': measureerror,
         'id' : id
        }
    )
    df = df[df.qualifier.str.contains('first')]
    met_sids = df.race.unique()
    pprint(met_sids)
    colorsIdx = {'rat': 'rgb(215,48,39)', 'cat': 'rgb(215,148,39)', 'dog':'rgb(215,148,20)'}
    cols = df['participant'].map(colorsIdx)

    for met_sid in met_sids:
        temp_df = df[df.race.str.contains(f'{met_sid}')]
        pprint(temp_df)
        data = [
            go.Scatter(
                x=temp_df['id'],
                y=temp_df['avgsteps'],
                error_y=dict(
                    type='data',
                    array=temp_df['measureerror'],
                    visible=True,
                ),
                mode='markers',
                marker=dict(size=15, color=cols)

            )
        ]
        plot(data, filename='error-bar.html')

classify_data()
```

Only problem is error bars don't have the same color as data point. Any suggestion on how to assign the same color for both value and error bar?

I'd be happy to know other approaches too